# IncludePath Wxwidgets on MacOS

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, wxwidgets

I tried all ways to install wx on the system, but VS Code doesn't recognize wx/wxprec.h and other libraries. I tried to install by cmake, homebrew but none of VS Code compiles directly. If I try to compile via terminal, it works perfectly. Could it be a problem with IncludePath?

In my includePath, i put:
    `includePath": [ "${workspaceFolder}/**", "/usr/local/Cellar/wxwidgets/3.2.2.1/include/wx-3.2", "/usr/local/include/wx-3.2", "/usr/local/lib/wx/include/osx_cocoa-unicode-3.2"]`

fatal error: 'wx/wxprec.h' file not found

I want to be able to compile via VS Code, without typing the library inclusion commands via terminal.

Comment: VS Code's `includePath` setting is only for intellisense, does not affect compiler behavior.

Comment: Why did you delete your question on [odd nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76097187/5459839). Was my answer not helpful? Is that how you will treat an answer on this question too?